# Unexpected alteration to composite primary key order in entity framework migration

Tags: entity-framework-6, xaf, entity-framework-migrations

I am upgrading the security in an xaf application [as per DevExpress help](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t418166/how-to-upgrade-an-existing-project-to-the-allow-deny-permission-policy-migrate-to)

My situation is complicated because I have a mapping from the payroll table to the user table.

I have found in the past that this mapping caused a need for some configuration classes

Thus I have the following in the DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PermissionPolicyUser>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithMany(y=> y.Users)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("PermissionPolicyRole_ID");
                m.MapRightKey("PermissionPolicyUser_ID");
                m.ToTable("PermissionPolicyUserPermissionPolicyRoles");
            });
    }
}

public class RoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PermissionPolicyRole>
{
    public RoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Users).WithMany(y=> y.Roles)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("PermissionPolicyUser_ID");
                m.MapRightKey("PermissionPolicyRole_ID");
                m.ToTable("PermissionPolicyUserPermissionPolicyRoles");
            });
    }
}
```

When I generate the migration I was surprised to see the primary key columns reordered

```
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.PermissionPolicyUserPermissionPolicyRoles");
AddPrimaryKey("dbo.PermissionPolicyUserPermissionPolicyRoles", new[] { "PermissionPolicyRole_ID", "PermissionPolicyUser_ID" });
```

My question is why did this happen and does it matter?